# How insert a string in next line for searched pattern in a file using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a file with Contents as below:-

```
He is good at python.
Python is not a language as well as animal.
Look for python near you.
Hello World it's great to be here.
```

Now, script should search for pattern "python" or "pyt" or "pyth" or "Python" or any regex related to "p/Python". After search of particular word, it should insert new word like "Lion". So output should become like below:-

```
He is good at python.
Lion
Python is not a language as well as animal.
Lion
Look for python near you.
Lion
Hello World it's great to be here.
```

How can I do that ?

NOTE:-
Till now I wrote code like this:-

```
def insertAfterText(args):
    file_name = args.insertAfterText[0]
    pattern = args.insertAfterText[1]
    val = args.insertAfterText[2]
    fh = fileinput.input(file_name,inplace=True)
    for line in fh:
        replacement=val+line
        line=re.sub(pattern,replacement,line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    fh.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're better off writing a new file, than trying to write into the middle of an existing file.

`with open` is the best way to open files, since it safely and reliably closes them for you once you're done. Here's a cool way of using `with open` to open two files at once:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'pyt', re.IGNORECASE)

filename = 'textfile.txt'
new_filename = 'new_{}'.format(filename)

with open(filename, 'r') as readfile, open(new_filename, 'w+') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        writefile.write(line)
        if pattern.search(line):
            writefile.write('Lion\n')
```

Here, we're opening the existing file, and opening a new file (creating it) to write to. We loop through the input file and simply write each line out to the new file. If a line in the original file contains matches for our regex pattern, we also write `Lion\n` (including the newline) after writing the original line.

Comment: Thanks @daveruinseverything , it's a good solution and serves the purpose but I want to make changes in original file only how can I do that?  Moreover, how to take inputs argument for regex 'pyt'

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a variable:

```
with open("textfile") as ff:
  s=ff.read()
```

Use regex and write the result back:

```
with open("textfile","w") as ff:
  ff.write(re.sub(r"(?mi)(?=.*python)(.*?$)",r"\1\nLion",s))

    (?mi): m: multiline, i.e. '$' will match end of line;
           i: case insensitiv;
    (?=.*python): lookahead, check for "python";
    Lookahead doesn't step forward in the string, only look ahead, so:
    (.*?$) will match the whole line, 
     which we replace with self '\1' and the other.
```

Edit:
To use from command line insert:

```
import sys
textfile=sys.argv[1]
pattern=sys.argv[2]
newtext=sys.argv[3]
```

and replace

```
r"(?mi)(?=.*python)(.*?$)",r"\1\nLion"
```

with

```
fr"(?mi)(?=.*{pattern})(.*?$)",r"\1{newtext}"
```

and in open() change "textfile" to textfile.

Comment: thanks it seems to be working but can you make it a command line?
like I have to give - python abc.py filename pattern newtext